# Gatsbyjs build error when using jarallax javascript library

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

using Gatsby v2.

I want to use jarallax javascript library (https://free.nkdev.info/jarallax/) in order to put some parallax effect on my index page. It is not a react component, so in order to avoid any incompatibility I just wrap it in a component like:

```
import React from "react"
import { jarallax } from "jarallax"

class Jarallax extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    jarallax(document.querySelectorAll(".jarallax"), { speed: 0.2 })
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    jarallax(document.querySelectorAll(".jarallax"), "destroy")
  }
  render() {
    return null
  }
}

export default Jarallax
```

And then in the IndexPage when I want to use it, I just import the component and simply use it like `<Jarallax />` and *It works on develop*

I do also have this `gatsby-node.js` file following the Gatsby documentation:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /flickity/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
          {
            test: /jarallax/, // <--
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Now, if I try to run `gatsby build` I'm facing this error (https://pastebin.com/CXVaQA5f), but as I'm pretty new to react and to gatsby, not really sure what is the next step now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this replacing `<Jarallax />` for `{typeof document !== "undefined" && <Jarallax />}` in my `IndexPage`

this helped me: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9038#issuecomment-432548071

Comment: Consider marking this answer as resolved if you can!

Comment: @JasonStallings is marked as resolved now, thanks !